# Sum of increasing power of a rational number formula?

Tags: power-series, rational-numbers

What is the formula to find the sum of increasing power of the same rational number? For example:

$$({2\over3})^0 + ({2\over3})^1 + ({2\over3})^2 + ({2\over3})^3 + ..... + ({2\over3})^{1000}$$
$$ = 1 + ({2\over3}) + ({2\over3})^2 + ({2\over3})^3 + ..... + ({2\over3})^{1000}$$
$$ = {1 ( 1 - ({2\over3})^{2001})\over{1-{2\over3}}}$$

I saw somewhere, but they did not explain how they got here. What is the name of the formula that allows us to get this?

PS: Sorry if it's a duplicate. Didn't know how to search it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the formula for the sum of a geometric series:

$1+r+r^2+...+r^n
=\dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}
$.

This is true for any complex
$r \ne 1$.

If you write it in the form

$(1-r)(1+r+r^2+...+r^n)
=1-r^{n+1}
$
it is true for all $r$.

Comment: Thanks. What if it didn’t start at 1?

Comment: If it starts at $r^k$, divide each term by $r^k$. The resulting series then starts at $1$. At the end, multiply by $r^k$ to get the original series.